# Where to include Underscore templates?

Tags: javascript, django, templates, underscore.js

What is the best place in the document to include Underscore Javascript templates?

So far I have seen templates being included within `<head>` or `<body>` tag.
What is more appropriate? Are there performance implications (speed of page load) for either approach?

I have my templates in separate files and use Django for backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you include your Javascript files within the `<head>` or `<body>` tag does not make a difference to the Django server. Any performance implications in this regard are entirely client-side, and have nothing to do with the server-side. They affect only how your page is rendered.

When it comes to Django, you should be looking at the [`staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) app, which manages the serving of static files for your application. This [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) should also help you get started with static files in Django.

Notice that you need to set different settings for static files in development and production environments; more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427643/how-to-attach-css-to-my-template/10427701#10427701).

Comment: Any advise on how to assess client-side implications?

Comment: @Shvetusya Client-side implications are usually dependent on the specific case (that's why I didn't go into them). For instance, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315982/are-scripts-not-in-head-ok). There are both advantages and disadvantages; depending on the situation at hand.

Comment: @Shvetusya Also, the client-side framework (Underscore in your case) might dictate whether to put your `JS` files in either the `head` or `body` tags. Read the docs.